# Prove by mathematical induction $n < 2n$

Tags: inequality, induction

Prove the following by mathematical induction

$n < 2n$, for all positive integer $n$.

This is what I have done:

**Step 1:**
$n=1$: $1 < 2$

**Step 2:**
$k < 2k$

$n=k+1$: $(k+1) < 2(k+1)$

$k + 1 < 2k + 1 < 2k + 2 = 2(k+1)$

Hence $P(k+1)$ is true whenever $P(k)$ and since $P(1)$ is true.

I didn't write all necessary assumptions but can anyone help me to check if my method is correct or if it needs improvements. Thank you.

Comment: The argument looks fine but the presentation could use some improvement.

Comment: It seems correct. Just try to be more explicit in your steps by saying. "this is our induction hypothesis"... "this is what we'll prove"...

Comment: What is your definition of "$<$"?

Comment: when you say $k+1<k+k$, you should stipulate $k>1$

Comment: For $$k=1$$ the proof was given by the OP

Answer (score -1):

We have to prove that $$n+1<2(n+1)$$ , adding $1$ on both sides of $$n<2n$$ we get
$$n+1<2n+1$$ and $$2n+1<2(n+1)$$ so the proof is finished.

Comment: This is induction